# selecting values from two tables mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables `accounts` and `confirm_email`. `confirm_email` has a column called `code` and `accounts` has a column called `email` and they both have a column called `account_name` I am trying to select the `code` from `confirm_email` and the `email` from `accounts` where the the value of `account_name` is the same in both and equal to a specific value. So basicaly I want to combine these two comands:

```
SELECT email FROM accounts WHERE account_name = 'value';
SELECT code FROM confirm_email WHERE account_name = 'value';
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT code, email FROM confirm_email, accounts WHERE accounts.account_name = 'value';
```

but this returned all codes in the `code` column with the `email` corrosponding to the correct `code` repeaded for each `code` value. Any ideas how to combine the two querys into one correctly? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT c.code, a.email 
FROM confirm_email c join accounts a on a.account_name = c.account_name
WHERE a.account_name = 'value';
```

When you join two tables you need to set a joining condition.

The old-style (without JOIN keyword):

```
SELECT c.code, a.email 
FROM confirm_email c, accounts a
WHERE a.account_name = c.account_name 
  and a.account_name = 'value';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this inner join

```
SELECT confirm_email.code, accounts.email 
FROM confirm_email inner join accounts 
ON confirm_email.account_name = accounts.account_name
WHERE accounts.account_name = 'value';
```